What is the differemce between shani mahardhasha and sade satti?
I am seeing in quora site that some people mentioning shani mahardhasha lasts for 19 years, but I have my sade satti starting now until 2030 as per vedicscholar web site.
Are they not both same?  What are the actual effects of both of them?
